# Issues parsing a test file with ANTLRv4

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

I've defined a grammar in ANTLRv4, as well as written a small example file to test it's parsing, and it is constantly giving me the error:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'import' expecting 'class'
```

the test file is http://pastebin.com/ThpuexL5

the grammar file is http://pastebin.com/6PAUHzrT

I have no idea why the grammar I've written is trying to match to 'class' instead of 'import' even though I've defined that import should come first.

Comment: Can you also include the code which runs your test?

Comment: Are you sure to use the correct start rule for your grammer? A quick run with grun seems to work at least for the first few lines of sample code.

Comment: looks like the start rule is "baseClass" cause this is the only case that can only start with "class".

Comment: I tried to, SO complained. The driver file that executes the code is [this](http://pastebin.com/epqGCBEk)

Comment: Also, fileStart should be the starting rule, because it's the first one defined.